# vim copying and pasting different length characters on multiple lines

Tags: vim

I have the following shell script :

```
STORAGE_PORT='7000'
API_PORT='10000'
CLIENT_PORT='9042'
```

and I would like it to become :

```
STORAGE_PORT='7000'
API_PORT='10000'
CLIENT_PORT='9042'

STORAGE_PORT:STORAGE_PORT
API_PORT:API_PORT
CLIENT_PORT:CLIENT_PORT
```

Is there an elegant way in vim to do that ? (without having to copy paste individually every variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would place the cursor on the first line

```
gg0
```

then start recording a macro

```
qq
```

then do the first line manually

```
ywjjo<ESC>pa:<ESC>p0kk
```

and stop recording the macro

```
q
```

then repeat the macro twice, or as much as as needed

```
@q@q
```

Comment: `gg` is sufficient, there is no need for `gg0`. Else it is a nice solution.

Comment: `0k` can probably be replaced with `-`. See `:h -`. I find `-`, `+`, and `<cr>` to be very helpful creating nice repeatable macros

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the whole block, and then replace the second part with a regex:

```
ggyGGp:,$s/^\v(.*)\=.*/\1:\1/g
```

But you could also use a macro in various forms

While `ggyGGp` is a set of commands which a vim user uses quite fluently, the comment from Peter under the answer of Ingo made me remember that it is also quite a beginner way to do it (hey i am still learning so it is alright).

`:%t0` is may more elegant, it `t` is a synonym for copying, `%` means everyline and `0` means to line zero. So my regex solution would look like that:

```
:%t0<cr>o<esc><cr>:,$s/^\v(.*)\=.*/\1:\1/g
```

This is still 8 chars longer than Peters Golf solution but I can live with that, since golf is only for the posh and rich.

Comment: Didn't know about %t, thanks ! Not looking particularly for golf solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:global` to iterate over all lines (that start with the variable; we can then later reuse the search pattern for capture via the `gn` command), and *append* to an (uppercase) register that we pre-initialize with a newline, so the register is *linewise* and each added variable is separated with a newline character:

```
:let @a="\n"|g/^\w\+/norm! "Aygn
:put a
```

#### code golf

In order to shorten this further, we can replace the pattern with a simple `^` (so that all lines match), and use `t=` to just capture the variable:

```
:let @a="\n"|g/^/norm! "Ayt=
:put a
```

Comment: while as always a interesting approach and it sort of answers the question in the title, I have to inform you that it will not produce the desired output. However it is a valid first step to the desired output and I quite like the idea with the `register` and `put` logic to add to the end of the file, must remember that one! Thanks you for that!

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: You're right, it doesn't go all the way. I treated the doubling of the variable and the different separator as pecularities of the example, not as part of the generalization.

Comment: More golf: `:%t0<cr>o<esc><cr>:,$norm ywwC:<c-v><c-r>0<cr>`

Comment: @PeterRincker thats a really nice solution, I tried something similar but just couldn't remember the `<c-v>`, it wasn't a good day yesterday... However there is no excuse for overseeing the `:t` command `head`->`table`. Thank you, now my answer doesn't look like somebody with big fingers mashed the `g` key anymore!

Comment: unione seems to have an even shorter golf: `ggqqywjjo<ESC>pa:<ESC>p-kq@q@qo`

Comment: I think I will reuse the technique you described quite often, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

While I really like the compact ways described in other answers, here is a more step by step explanation.

First copy the 3 lines to the new location.

Then visually select them. Go to the first line and hit `Vjj`. `V` start linewise-visual and then move down two lines.

Then hit `:`. The cursor jumps to the command line, which is per-populated with `'<,'>`. This means that the command will only be executed on the visually selected lines (see `:help v_:`).  Then enter the command

```
'<,'>s/^\([^=]*\)=.*$/\1:\1/
```

This matches the variable name from the beginning of the line (`^`) until before the `=` char and stores as "group 1" (`\(...\)` denotes a group). It also matches then till end of line (`.*$`). The replacement replaces the entire line with "group 1" (`\1`) followed by `:` and then again "group 1".

Comment: This is better explained than my answer, but nearly identical.
`ggyGGp` copys the lines to the bottom. 
`:.,$` is a range which is in this case the same range as your `'<,'>` and your regex does exactly the same as mine. While the additional explaining may be wort ah answer, I must object to the word "cryptic".

Comment: How about changing it to "compact" ?

Comment: Mine is also shorter :) No it is alright, no bad feelings. As I said, your additional Information may help the person asking. I just wanted to point out, that there are a lot of ways in vim to do exactly the same, and that you have to check other answers for that, else we would have 300 different regex patterns (of course if you think yours is better, and explain why it is better, it is perfectly fine). Have a nice day!